# How to determine the precise (i.e., not just the order of magnitude) Big-Oh values based on the number of statement executions?

Tags: data-structures, big-o

I am studying Data Structures, but I am a bit confused about my homework assignment. I am trying to figure out how to count the precise Big-Oh values of the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = i; j < n; j++)
    {
        for (int k = j; k < n; k++)
        {
            sum += j;
        }
    }
}
```

I know how to count the Big-Oh's in terms of magnitude, but I don't know how to count it precisely. An example answer is in the form: 10N + 3n^2 + 2 (IE)

Comment: Well, calculate the number of statements in the innermost loop with relation to the outer variables (in this case j). Then calculate the same thing for the middle loop (you already know the number of statements in the inner loop with relation to j, just sum them up along all values of j). Then sum all that over all possible values of i. It's going to be a sum of sums, the inner sums being dependant on the value of the outer variables.. Good luck.

Comment: Would it be 1 + 2n + n(1 + 2n + n(1+ 3n + 1) + 1) + 1? It was a multiple choice question and this wasnt a choice. What am I counting wrong? Thanks